# Access Sharepoint from console using token

Tags: 2013, office-365, authentication, credentials, oauth

I want to access a Sharepoint 2013 / office365 - site  from a console application using OAuth-token I saved earlier using a provider hosted app.

I already can connect using credentials:

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://mypage.sharepoint.com))
{
  context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
  context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(_username, secureString);
  return context;
}
```

But instead of using _username, secureString (=password) I want to use the saved Token. How can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just regenerate the token.

Add the App For SharePoint nuget package to your console app.

```
Install-Package AppForSharePointWebToolkit
```

Then write the code to generate the token and context object.

```
Uri siteUri = new Uri(siteUrl);
string realm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(siteUri); string accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, siteUri.Authority, realm).AccessToken;

ClientContext ctx = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(siteUri.ToString(), accessToken);
```

You'll also need to put the Client ID and secret into your console app's app.config.

Comment: Thanks. can the clientId and ClientSecret from the console Application be the same as the application that stores the credentials?

Comment: Yes. Try it and see.